# "user was removed" again

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts

This time (seven hours ago, apparently), my "reputation" went down by 208 points, so it must have been someone who's done a lot of posting here.

It's hard not to suspect that users who've been around a while and insist on having their accounts removed do so because something offended them.  And the secrecy surrounding these incidents is annoying.

Here's a fact: The way stackexchange functions tacitly encourages certain behaviors that offend good people.  Is anyone who can do so thinking about altering the design of the way the site functions, to address these issues?

Comment: Ouch! I lost 100 today, as well.

Comment: Your "fact" contains both the very vague phrase "certain behaviors" and the very questionable phrase "good people." It is like no other fact I have ever seen. It more closely resembles what is usually called "rhetoric" or perhaps "polemic."

Comment: Many user removals seem to be correlated to contentious meta topics, e.g. most recently the issue of contests. These could be handled *much* better. Far too often  arguments get personal, e.g. folks flamebait others by purposely distorting opponent's positions, and other unethical debating techniques. One particularly bad recent example was accusing opponents of contest problem deletion of supporting cheating. Of course no one supports cheating. If you see problems like this please *flag them immediately* so that we can keep discussion polite and rational, focused on topics, not personalities.

Comment: I lost 70 this time. This is becoming annoyingly frequent.

Comment: Sorry, not impressed --- I lost 390.

Comment: I lost 160. I don't know if this data is useful...

Comment: I am getting tired of the policy on deleted people, thinking of leaving. Might take it happening a couple more times. It makes it unreasonable to attempt to answer questions of obviously somewhat troubled people.

Comment: @Andre and Michael The community can help alleviate these problems. We need more help on meta: more voices of reason, more eyes watching out for sparks before they become flames, more experienced members to help lead, etc.

Comment: I'm not earning enough to keep up with all the losses due to user removal!

Comment: I lost 75 out of 6549, so I might have lost the most proportionally out of all who have mentioned it so far (oh, I guess Austin beat me easily).  They loved me, whoever they were.  But, as long as the posts are still here, it doesn't really matter.  I think it's weird that people leave like this though.  You don't prove anything by leaving, except that you're not willing to work with others.

Comment: Ha -- I just got +2 by a user being removed! :-)

Comment: Gerry beat me again, this time by 78: I lost ‘only’ 312. (Last time we had this discussion he beat me by 2.)

Comment: Michael, I don’t think that your last paragraph is polemical, but it is both vague (‘certain behaviors’) and ambiguous (‘good people’). (1) It would be helpful to give an example or three of such behaviors. (2) Do you mean ‘people who contribute usefully’, ‘people with pleasant online personae’, or what?

Comment: @joriki: What a surprise! :-)

Comment: @Gone You will hardly avoid "flamebait" by only seeing problems with posts from the "other side" and wanting to solve the problem by deleting them.

Comment: I do not understand why this happens to much. What is wrong with just forgetting about a site - why do people feel the need to delete their account entirely?

Comment: I find it disturbingly gratifying in an entirely inexplicable way to increase my 'reputation' here, and find myself childishly peeved when the count goes down because someone left. However, at the end of the day the point is to help and share knowledge, and this site enables this. Think beyond the user deletions.

Comment: (-1) I originally voted this up due to the potential for a good question to result, but find myself forced to revise that vote for the following reasons: (1) Several users have asked for clarification regarding the only actual question stated in the post without any response and (2) the question as stated is so vague in its present form so as to be unanswerable. That leaves only the commentary as actual content. I'm also **voting to close** for the same reasons, though I'm hoping what will actually happen is that this post will be edited into an answerable form.

Comment: This is dismally familiar.  It seems to be happening with increasing frequency.

Comment: @joriki  I got a +2 from a user removed once too.

Comment: @joriki: You got +2, I actually got a badge when a user was removed!

Comment: @Asaf: We should found ABSURD, the Association of Beneficiaries of Stackexchange User Removal and Deletion :-)

Answer (score 18):

Often, these deletions are handled by a single moderator, or even by an SE staff member, and the circumstances are not published unless the person requesting deletion decides to make the issue public in chat or comments. This is simply to protect users' privacy.

You mention that SE encourages behaviors that offend good people. It would be easier to alter the way the site functions if we had examples of these encouraged offensive behaviors. (I feel like someone asking the person who lost the $\$100$ bill to form a line at Lost and Found).

Comment: (+1) Especially for the last paragraph. The only way SE or the community can address perceived problems/issues is if we actually know what they are. :-)

Comment: Agreed. Users have the right to remove their accounts and there is no reason this should have to be publicly announced every time it happens. I do not understand what is objectionable about this. Do people really care about reputation _that_ much?

Comment: The part of this I have never understood is why protecting a user's privacy requires undoing the effect of their votes. What can't the account be closed, and left inactive, with the identifying biographical information scrubbed off it? Is this a technical issue, or is there some privacy issue I am overlooking?

Comment: The removal of votes has nothing to do with privacy. It has to do with how deleted accounts are handled. Some details are provided in [this question and its answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I see a lot of details, but no actual reasons.

Comment: @MJD: "A lot of details, but no actual reasons." Indeed. Welcome to meta.stackexchange.com, enjoy your stay. :)

Comment: @MJD The main concern seems to be the possibility of hard to detect vote fraud when the votes would be kept for deleted users. And the technical difficulties of implementing this properly. At least that is what I understand from some answers by SE employees.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Having the right to do something and something being the right thing to do are vastly different.  On this site, though it's not a close relationship for most, there is a relationship between people.  So, when someone just deletes their account and leaves, it's somewhat analogous to one of your friends just leaving town and never telling you.  We can hide behind the fact that we're on the internet, but we're all still people too.  I just think the people doing such things are acting like children more often than not.  The reputation doesn't matter.

Comment: Obviously votes should be removed when an account is deleted. Otherwise you could create sockpuppets to upvote your own posts and then delete them.

Comment: @Graphth: I don't think the analogy holds water. One reason to delete an account is if it can in some way be tied to the rest of your internet presence (e.g. because you posted under your real name or under a name you use elsewhere) and you don't want that tie for whatever reason.

Comment: @Qiaochu: No, it isn’t obvious, as is evident from the number of us who are unhappy with the policy. The odd sockpuppet boosting some poor sod’s reputation wouldn’t greatly distress me and would certainly be less intrusive and annoying.

Comment: @Brian: I don't understand your position. You're not okay with people losing reputation when accounts get deleted, but you _are_ okay with people _gaining_ reputation from deleted sockpuppets?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Yes. Why is that hard to understand? The former is a minor but on-going annoyance. It’s very unlikely that I’ll even notice the latter, which doesn’t really affect anyone but the poor sod who needs the boost to his ego. Moreover, I don’t expect it to be a very common occurrence.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: the fact that there are two cases here: accounts deleted for voting fraud and those for other reasons; indicates that we might want to discuss two different options for deletion: removing votes and not.

Comment: @Brian: I don't understand why people losing reputation when accounts get deleted is annoying. This happens roughly proportionally, so it doesn't affect the correlation between reputation and whatever you think reputation usefully correlates with, which deleted sockpuppets does.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I already pointed out the fact that it’s very noticeable. It’s also dishonest: those upvotes existed. But it doesn’t really matter whether you understand, so long as you accept the simple fact is that some of us find it so. *I* don’t understand why you’re so worried about the possibility of a few unearned upvotes here and there.

Comment: @BRian: "a few unearned upvotes here and there"? The current way that the system detects voting fraud is to look for too many votes from a user to another user in a short period of time (as far as I can tell). This could be bypassed by creating an arbitrary number of sockpuppets, and if you think this wouldn't happen then you aren't familiar with Chandru1.... I accept your position but still do not understand it because I do not understand why you value reputation, or more precisely I do not understand why the reason you value reputation triggers for uniform loss of reputation but not...

Comment: ...for non-uniform (and deceitful) gain.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Oh, I’m quite sure that it would happen occasionally. **I don’t care**, provided that it occurs only occasionally. And if there’s already machinery in place to catch egregious instances, that’s fine; apply appropriate penalties to the offenders and delete their fraudulent upvotes. That has nothing to do with and would not affect the rest of us. As for *uniform loss*: it certainly isn’t literally true, and I’m not at all sure that it’s even statistically true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It is basic human psychology that 1) losses weigh more heavily than gains, 2) an action that is against us personally with a perceived motive (*my* rep has been stolen by a *deliberate* act) weighs more heavily than a (perceived) "victim-less" crime like sock-puppeting. The whole rep system is engineered to tap into basic human psychology, it is highly inconsistent to then complain that people should behave "rationally" when human psychology suddenly becomes inconvenient.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is with having a rep floor above which the votes are not deleted.  Surely the situation of having say 3K+ sock puppet accounts is rare enough that it could be dealt with manually if it ever happened.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I am sure that the real problems are *technical* problems. (Votes have to be assigned to a user, if all votes of deleted users are assigned to the same dummy user, this user will exceed vote caps, if the votes are assigned to different dummy users, then deletion of an account is just a user name change.) Unfortunately, SE officals have a tendency to get defensive on technical issues and try to find other reasons.

Comment: @robjohn: Did you mean to say "lost the $\$100$ Gone"? (Too soon?)

Comment: @NoahSnyder That is already done for users with a very high amount of votes, SE has a manual deletion process that keeps the votes (I think they get assigned to the community user), though that one is used rarely. I agree that there should be better solutions than the current, very unsatisfying one (I wrote the highly upvoted feature request abou that on Meta.SO), we'll see if SE changes anything about this.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether to feel better or worse over losing a mere 40 pts. in this episode!  However the discussion prompts me to mention an observation that I've been mulling over.

In many (many) ways Math.SE is the "smoothest" running of the StackExchange sites I frequent.  I have more occasion to flag questions and answers on other of these sites, and (in my eyes) the policy for closing questions is more clearly and consistently applied here.  In some measure this can be rationalized as due to the more objective (less emo) subject matter, but I think it's a credit to our users and moderators alike.

The business of removed users is the one flaw in this comparison.  I don't recall seeing this on another SE site.  Probably it happens, though I'm not sure how often, but if it seems more noticeable on Math.SE, perhaps that indicates we are a more closely knit community than many.

No MSE user is an island!